# What algorithm can I use to recursively load an entire directory, starting from a specified path?

Tags: c#, algorithm, c#-3.0, directory-structure

I'm building a custom file dialog, and my problem is its taking too long to load.

The dialog begins with an `InitialDirectory` property, and I am looking to find a way to load the directory tree for the `InitialDirectory` first, followed by the rest of the directories in a background thread.

For example, if the `InitialDirectory` was `C:\Users\User12345\MyDocuments`, then it should load all folders in

```
C:\
C:\Users
C:\User12345
C:\Users\User12345\MyDocuments
```

then kick off a background thread to load all the remaining directories.

Is there an fast and easy way to use recursion to load first the `InitialDirectory`, than everything else, without duplicating any items?

I'm struggling to find a high-performing way to do this, since checking for the existance of a folder with code like `if (!Directory.Contains(f => f.FullName == folder.FullName))` slows down the load by quite a bit.

My current code to load the full directory looks something like this:

```
private void LoadDirectory()
{
    string root = @"C:\";
    var rootNode = new DirectoryModel() { Name = root, FullName = root };
    this.Directory.Add(rootNode);

    DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(root);
    IEnumerable<DirectoryInfo> subDirectories = info.GetDirectories()
            .Where(d => ((d.Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) != FileAttributes.Hidden)
                && ((d.Attributes & FileAttributes.System) != FileAttributes.System));

    LoadDirectories(subDirectories, root);
}

private void LoadDirectories(IEnumerable<DirectoryInfo> subDirs, string parentName)
{
    IEnumerable<DirectoryInfo> subdirectories;
    foreach (DirectoryInfo folder in subDirs)
    {
        var node = new DirectoryModel() { Name = folder.Name, FullName = folder.FullName, ParentName = parentName };

        Directory.Add(node);

        try
        {
            subdirectories = folder.GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                .Where(d => ((d.Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) != FileAttributes.Hidden)
                    && ((d.Attributes & FileAttributes.System) != FileAttributes.System));
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
        {
            continue;
        }
        catch (System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException e)
        {
            continue;
        }

        if (subdirectories.Count() != 0)
            LoadDirectories(subdirectories, folder.FullName);
    }
}
```

Note that the `Directory` collection is a flat collection - there is no hierarchy in the data models.

Comment: `folder.GetDirectories` this returns a `DirectoryInfo[]`, not an `IEnumerable<...>`. In this way you can use Length (but it doesn't change anything)... And normally it's better to use `Any()` instead of `Count() != 0`

Comment: @xanatos Thanks. I had the IEnumerable there so I wouldn't have to bother with `.ToList()` after the Linq statements (I might have been testing with it at some point too)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on *how* you present to the user your data, imo.

If you use a `TreeView` control, you can easily avoid to load all data in background, but just load only the *root* of your tree (like you already do as much as I understood).

In this way, having a procedure that loads all sub-directory names and files of a specified directory you just need to wait until user clicks on the `[+]` in order to see the directory content interesting *to him*. So you run your procedure and populate the tree.

This is actually highest performant way known to me to deal with this kind of stuff, and actually you will find this pattern almost in all "explorer like" products. 
The performance here achieved not by perfectly refined algorithm, but just by defining more convenient behavioral model.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm attempting to make this work, but it's being hindered by a few problems. For one, I'm binding to a DevExpress TreeView, and the `[+]` icon won't show up unless there's items under that node. In addition, users have the option of typing a URL into a TextBox, and it will automatically expand to that node, which doesn't work if the node doesn't exist already.

Comment: @Rachel: correct. That actually almost all known to me controls work like. You can say: if this is a directory add a DUMMY chld to it, so control will visualize `[+]` as there is something under it, but at the moment user actually clicks that sign, first I remove DUMMY, after add scanned children.

Comment: @Rachel: in case of URL passed directly, naturally, there is no other option, then decompose it in subpaths, and check if you have them already load, if not load them and go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

To give a face to Tigran's solution, one way to accomplish this is by using something like the following:

1. Subscribe to the tree's BeforeExpand event.

   ```
   private void BeforeExpand(object sender, BeforeExpandEventArgs e)
   {
       TreeListNode current = e.Node;

       if (current.Nodes.Count > 0)
           return;

       if (current.Tag is DriveInfo)
       {
           exampleTree.BeginUpdate();
           DriveInfo driveInfo = current.Tag as DriveInfo;
           LoadDirectories(current, driveInfo.RootDirectory);
           exampleTree.EndUpdate(true);
       }
       else if (current.Tag is DirectoryInfo)
       {
           exampleTree.BeginUpdate();
           LoadDirectories(current, (DirectoryInfo)current.Tag);
           exampleTree.EndUpdate(true);
       }
   }
   ```

And here is the LoadDirectories() method:

```
    private void LoadDirectories(TreeListNode parent, DirectoryInfo directoryInfo)
    {
        DirectoryInfo[] directories = directoryInfo.GetDirectories();
        foreach (DirectoryInfo directory in directories)
        {
            if ((directory.Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) == FileAttributes.Hidden) continue;
            TreeListNode child = new TreeListNode() { Tag = directory, Text = directory.Name };
            parent.Nodes.Add(child);
        }

        FileInfo[] files = directoryInfo.GetFiles();
        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            TreeListNode child = new TreeListNode() { Tag = file, Text = file.Name };
            parent.Nodes.Add(child);
        }
    }
```

HTH,

-saige-